# How to move a plone install on the file system

Tags: plone

Is it possible to make copied of plone/zope folder on the file system and still be able to run the site?

At the moment when I try to start it, it says

```
bash: ./bin/instance: /home/atf/Plone-3.3.6/Python-2.4/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

looking for python in the old folder. How can I update this and are other things likely to be broken after fixing this?

Comment: This is on my desktop system, so I don't want to change the python path for my whole OS (ubuntu).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It currently thinks your python is at:

`/home/atf/Plone-3.3.6/Python-2.4/bin/python`

Just re-run bootstrap with the new python:

`/path/to/where/python/is/now bootstrap.py`

Then

`./bin/buildout`